# Que Sera, Sera! Net Framework 4.0 support for SQL 2008?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0, sqlclr

I did substantial work  developing CLR routines to implement DAL functionality using VS2010 intending to port them to SQL2008R2 clr assemblies;
Did the unit testing, everything seemed fine.. 
Then the day came to put them in to SQL CLR assemblies..
Alas!, SQL2008 only support assemblies that are below framework 3.5 !
Days spent adopting  c# 4.0  functionality, now have to be thrown away and slide back to c#2.0. spending yet few more days.

Can I use Framework 4 CLR assemblies with  SQL2010  ?

Will there be support for framework 4.0 support in SQL2008R2 ? if so when ?

Comment: I suggest you post this question directly to Microsoft via their forums.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will there be support for framework 4.0 support in SQL2008R2 ? if so when ?

http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/10/16/sql-server-2008-sqlclr-net-framework-version/

> SQL Server 2008 and the forthcoming
>   SQL Server 2008 R2 release, previously
>   codenamed "Kilimanjaro", will both
>   continue to load the latest service
>   release of the version 2.0 CLR.
>
> You might be wondering, what is the
>   rationale behind SQL Server continuing
>   to load version 2.0 of the CLR? Is it
>   merely a healthy cautious attitude so
>   existing UDT's, UDA's, etc. are not
>   broken; or is it because additional
>   engineering would be required to
>   support the new CLR?
>
> It seems the answer is actually a
>   little of both.
>
> With the .net framework 4.0 we now
>   have the ability to load two or more
>   distinct versions of the CLR within a
>   single process. In previous releases
>   of the .net framework, a process could
>   only load a single instance of the
>   CLR. Given this restriction the CLR
>   team recommended that hosts, such as
>   SQL Server, use the LockClrVersion
>   function to determine the version of
>   the CLR to load prior to
>   initialization. So, as stated
>   previously, SQL Server 2008 and SQL
>   Server 2008 R2 will continue to load
>   the latest service release of the
>   version 2.0 CLR as the version is
>   locked before initialization of the
>   CLR begins.
>
> **While future versions of SQL Server
>   may load newer versions of the CLR, or
>   even support the loading of multiple
>   CLR's within the process, version 2.0
>   of the CLR is here to stay for SQLCLR
>   within SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server
>   2008 R2.**

Also, [a little bit more here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2009/12/09/sql-server-express-and-net-4.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the links, on the second link it says there is a sp for suppoting framework 4 beta on sqlexpress 2008..,Is there a hotfix or sp that enables framework 4 (release) on sql2008r2 standard ?

Comment: From the article: **Does all SQL Server Express functionality work with .NET Framework 4 Beta 2?** No, there are few features that still require .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 or 3.5 SP1. These features will be disabled if .NET Framework 4 Beta 2 is the only .NET Framework on the machine, but will start working the moment .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 or 3.5 SP1 is installed.
The list of features that don’t work with .NET Framework 4 Beta 2:
... The CLR user-defined types, functions, aggregates, procedures, and triggers.